# Unexpected output while reading a csv file in a for loop

Tags: python, csv, sentiment-analysis

```
import csv
if __name__ == "__main__":
    words = ["great" , "thanks"]
    with open("data/sentiwordnet.tsv", "r") as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f,delimiter='\t')
        for word in xrange(len(words)):
             for row in reader:
                 if row['word_en'] == words[word]:
                    print float(row["positive"])
                    print float(row["negative"])
                    print row["synset"]
```

Results:

```
0.75
0.0 
124567
```

The results above are only for the 1st word, i.e. "great". The loop ends here - it doesn't go on to the next word.

Comment: Are you sure the if condition is true for any words past your first one

Comment: Maybe `thanks` does not exist in your file?

Comment: You could use `for word in words:` instead to be more explicit in your variable naming.

Answer (score 5):

Once you iterate through the rows in `reader`, it won't magically restart. Swap the `for` loops so that you iterate only once through `reader`:

```
for row in reader:
    for word in xrange(len(words)):
```

I'd just avoid iterating twice by just checking if each word is in a set of words you're interested in. It'll run faster:

```
import csv

if __name__ == "__main__":
    words = {"great" , "thanks"}  # sets are faster than lists for checking containment

    with open("data/sentiwordnet.tsv", "r") as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter='\t')

        for row in reader:
            if row['word_en'] in words:
                print float(row["positive"])
                print float(row["negative"])
                print row["synset"]
```

You may also want to consider using a package like [pandas](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/urls/bitbucket.org/hrojas/learn-pandas/raw/master/lessons/01%20-%20Lesson.ipynb) for working with tables, it usually makes your life easier.